# Spring: Is it possible to lazy load all Spring Beans without @Lazy

Tags: spring

I am looking to lazy load all spring beans when running integration tests that utilize @ContextConfiguration. Ideally I would be able to apply this lazy loading in one place and have it applied to any beans that are loaded via the @ContextConfiguration annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

You can do this using `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor/BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.

```
@Configuration
static class LazyBeans implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr) throws BeansException {
        for (String name : bdr.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = bdr.getBeanDefinition(name);
            if (beanDefinition.getRole() == BeanDefinition.ROLE_APPLICATION) {
                beanDefinition.setLazyInit(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory clbf) throws BeansException {}
}
```